# Did drupal change body value and safe_value

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

So my page is displaying body from rich text editor. Before we were using `$variables["body"][0]["value"]`, but since recent this is stripped of all html tags like `<p><div><h1>` ...

Instead the `$variables["body"][0]["safe_value"]` has them and I'm not sure if it had it before. We aren't doing any prerendering our stuff like that.

Thanks for all the info, we are just trying to prevent this from happening again.

Comment: You have to check your editor configuration use "full html" ou "filtered html" format for your fields and take a look on tag authorized

Comment: My editor uses "full html". Not sure what you mean with tag authorized.

Comment: Do you have some modules installed like "HTMLPurifier" ?

Comment: We do have a lot of modules but not "HTMLPurifier"

Comment: And you don't have preprocess modifing those variables ?

Comment: No preprocess wither :/

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same issue. 
To me, it is a matter of obsolete php coding. 
One should just stop using the following codes :

```
print($variables["body"][0]["value"]);
```

or even

```
print($variables["body"][0]["safe_value"]);
```

Instead, use the render Drupal function :

```
print render($content['body']);
```